# vs_proweb.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010

Hey, I'm trying to install the Visual Studio 2010 Professional Trial. When I run 'vs_proweb.exe' I get an error saying

```
vs_probweb.exe is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've redownloaded multiple times and still same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `vs_proweb.exe` is corrupt.  If you have another computer available, try downloading that file on a different computer.  It is only 4.3MB and would be trivial to copy over on a flash drive.

If that doesn't work:  What browser are you using to download it?  Does the file size of your local copy match the reported size (4.3MB)?  Are you running any security software that could be tampering with executable files?  The more details the better.

Comment: Thanks! I tried downloading with IE instead of Firefox and worked perfectly.

Comment: it also works for other applications that I have downloaded from the Microsoft official site while using Google Chrome. Thx for the question and the answer.